# How do I display a webpage in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

How do I display a webpage on demand, in Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to launch Inernet Explorer with a specified webpage, use the [WebBrowserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394020%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

```
WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute);
webBrowserTask.Show();
```

If you want to embed a web browser **in** your app, use the [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431797%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser1" IsScriptEnabled="True" />
```

and in the code-behind:

```
webBrowser1.Source = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
```